# Relative compactness criterion in $\mathfrak{c}_{0}$

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness

I'm having trouble proving the following relative compactness criterion in $\mathfrak{c}_{0}$, the space of all sequences of complex numbers converging to $0$, with the metric $d((x_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}, (y_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}) = \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} |x_{n} - y_{n}|$:

$T \subseteq \mathfrak{c}_{0}$ is relatively compact iff there exists a sequence of positive real numbers $(x_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ such that $(x_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty} \in \mathfrak{c}_{0}$ for all $y \in T$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $|y_{n}|<x_{n}$.

I've only had an idea for one implication of the proof, and I'll outline it here (even though it's wrong, it's all I've got):

Let $\varepsilon >0$. For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we construct a finite $\frac{\varepsilon}{2^{n-1}}$-net $N_{n} = \{a^{(n1)},...,a^{(nm_{n})}\}$, and take $$x_{n} = \max_{1 \leq i \leq m_{n}}\left(|a_{n}^{(ni)}|+\frac{\varepsilon}{2^{n-2}}\right).$$

Such a sequence is indeed greater by modulo than any $y \in T$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, however, there is no guarantee that $x_{n} \to 0$, because I take out a new net for every $n$.

What would be a good approach to make sure that $x_{n} \to 0$? Also, what would the proof of the other implication look like?

Comment: What's your metric?

Comment: $d((x_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}, (y_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}) = \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} |x_{n} - y_{n}|$. I'll add it to the question.

Comment: @José_Carlos_Santos:The statement is obviously false the way it was formulated in my textbook, which your answer showed. However, I've added the additional condition: $(x_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty} \in \mathfrak{c}_{0}$, which is probably the correct formulation of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose first that $T$ is compact. For each $y\in\mathfrak{c}_0$ and each natural $n$, let $f_n(y)=|y_n|$. The function $f_n$ is continuous and therefore $f_n(T)$ is compact. Let $x_n=\sup_{y\in T}f_n(y)$. It is then trivially true that$$(\forall n\in\mathbb N)(\forall y\in T):|y_n|\leqslant x_n.\tag{1}$$I will prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=0$.

Suppose otherwise. Then there is a $\varepsilon>0$ such that the inequality $x_n\geqslant\varepsilon$ holds infinitely many times. On the other hand, since $T$ is compact, it is totally bounded. Therefore, there is a finite subset $\bigl\{y(1),y(2),\ldots,y(k)\bigr\}$ of $T$ such that$$T\subset\bigcup_{j=1}^kB\left(y(j),\frac\varepsilon3\right).\tag{2}$$Since each sequence $y(j)$ belongs to $\mathfrak{c}_0$, there is a natural number $N$ such that$$(\forall j\in\{1,2,\ldots,k\})(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):n\geqslant N\implies\bigl|y(j)_n\bigr|<\frac\varepsilon3.\tag{3}$$But it follows from $(2)$ and $(3)$ that $(\forall y\in T)(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):n\geqslant N\implies|y_n|<\frac23\varepsilon$, thereby contradicting the assertion that $x_n\geqslant\varepsilon$ infinitely often.

Let us see now the general case. If $T$ is relatively compact, then $\overline T$ is compact and therefore, as we have seen, there is a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\in\mathfrak{c}_0$ of non-negative real numbers such that$$(\forall n\in\mathbb N)\left(\forall y\in\overline T\right):|y_n|\leqslant x_n.$$Since $T\subset\overline T$, $(1)$ holds.

In order to prove the reverse implication, suppose that there is a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\in\mathfrak{c}_0$ of numbers greater than or equal to $0$ and let $T$ be the set of *all* sequences $y\in\mathfrak{c}_0$ such that $(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):|y_n|\leqslant x_n$. Then $T$ is closed and therefore, since $\mathfrak{c}_0$ is complete, $T$ is complete. So, in order to prove that $T$ is compact, all that remains to be proved is that $T$ is totally bounded, which is easy from the definition of $T$ and the fact that every bounded subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$ is totally bounded. And, since $T$ is compact, every subset of $T$ is relatively compact.

Comment: But $T \subseteq \mathfrak{c}_{0}$, and the constant sequence $1$ doesn't converge to $0$.

Comment: @MatijaSreckovic Right. I've edited my answer. Please take a look at it.

Comment: T isn't necessarily compact, it's only relatively compact, i.e. $\overline{T}$ is compact. The reason why I'm nitpicking about this is that, while the continuous image of a compact set is compact, the continuous image of a relatively compact set isn't necessarily relatively compact.

Comment: A subset is relatively compact if and only if it is a subset of a compact subset.

Comment: I understand that that equivalence holds. However, I don't understand why assuming that T is compact isn't a loss of generality. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: @MatijaSreckovic Sure. Suppose that $T$ is relatively compact. Then $\overline T$ is compact and I proved that there is a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of non-negative real numbers such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=0$ and that $(\forall y\in\overline T)(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):|y_n|\leqslant x_n$. Since $T\subset\overline T$, $T$ has the same property.

Comment: @MatijaSreckovic I saw that you tried to edit my answer and that that edition was rejected by [Shailesh](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/241153/shailesh) and by [Leucippus](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/148155/leucippus) (and I would have rejected it too if I was in their place). I have expanded my answer. Please tell me if you are satisfied now.

Comment: Yes, I was very satisfied with the answer before the edition as well. I didn't mean the edition as a correction of your proof/post, I just still had some difficulties with the reverse implication (supposing there exists a sequence etc... the last paragraph in your posto) despite the fact that your original post gave all the necessary information for the proof to be deduced easily, so I thought that if another person were to have trouble with this problem (and if they're having trouble with this problem, they're probably still inexperienced at these kinds of proofs, like me), they would find it

Comment: helpful to see a detailed proof (which is quite possibly incorrect or too detailed, since I don't claim to be an expert proof-writer). Of course, I was aware while writing the edit that the point of this site isn't to spoon-feed proofs to people, but rather give them ideas, so I was not surprised that it was rejected (possibly because of the quality of the edit itself). I apologize if my attempted edit came off as trying to correct anything, I was only thinking along the lines "I found this part hard, even though it's not supposed to be, maybe some other people would find it hard too."

Answer (score 0):

Ther is a mistake in the previus answer. (2) and (3) are properties only for elements in $T\subset c_0$, but the suposse is $(x_n)_n\notin c_0$ then the properties 2 and 3 don't apply for $(x_n)_n$. But by definition of supremum you can take $y\in c_0$ such that $x_n-\epsilon/3<y_n$, then
\begin{eqnarray}
2\epsilon/3<x_n-\epsilon/3<y_n<2\epsilon/3
\end{eqnarray}
We have a contradiction. Then $(x_n)_n \in c_0.$